# How to implement HTML "Plugins" for Weebly Website Builder

Tags: html, plugin

I've been using Weebly for a year now and I want to use its embed code feature to maximize customization.  I want to use Bootstrap or another HTML "plug-in", but I can't get that to work.

Is there any way to implement an HTML plug-in into a Weebly site?
(I'm not asking for a recommendation of anything, I just want to know how to apply a plugin to a Weebly site.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Josh S. of Weebly support,

> Unfortunately, this is not an available feature yet. Presently, you can directly modify the HTML & CSS of your website template using the 'Edit HTML / CSS ' option under the 'Design' tab of the editor. However, this feature should be used only if you're familiar with HTML & CSS code as we do not provide support for problems that may occur while using this area of the editor.

So plugins only work if you add the CSS to the Weebly site under the Design tab. (I just downloaded Bootstrap CSS and JS, and uploaded it to my site.)

Answer (score 1):

Weebly is self-contained. You can only add their components.

To "maximize customization" you need standard web hosting.

Comment: Can you provide a source that explains this?

Comment: The folks at Weebly will be better able to explain why you can't use Bootstrap: http://www.weebly.com/contact/. Would you like me to explain  web hosting?

Comment: I'm not too familiar with what web hosting is, so a brief description would be nice. Thank you for the link as well.

Comment: I've contacted Weebly on the subject.  Just waiting for them to respond now...